# What Would be My Best Option for Connecting the Parts of this Mesh?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging

I recently bought a mesh from the unity asset store of some really high quality FPS game arms. The mesh is awesome but doesn't come rigged. I was able to rig it up easily enough however due to the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Animating it doesn't really work all too well since the fingers, hand, and forearm disconnect from the rest of the mesh if rotated too much. I've tried using the merge faces but selecting the ring around the inside of the glove and inside of the fingertip doesn't connect them it only closes both holes. I tried heavily weight painting the parts of the mesh which works for the fingertips but not for the wrist or forearm. How can I better connect these parts of the mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge is probably merging everything at the center of the selected edge's bounding box.

You could do it manually, just enable edge snap and move the edges from the glove into the fingers and hands.
After you are done, select these edges (maybe grow the selection with ctrl + first, just to be sure), and then remove doubles.

Another way would be to select both edge loops, bridge them, then edge slide on the rings into the other and then remove doubles.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll have to look up most of what you've said lol still pretty new to modeling but thanks so much for the reply. I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: Did you have any luck?
If you have further questions let me know-

Comment: Yes! I was able to figure it out for the most part. I just need to refine a few things to make it look better like removing the extra faces you don't see, thanks so much for the help!